# Auto addition of a int and string

Tags: auto

#include

int main()
{

```
auto a = 1;
auto b = "Hello";
auto c = a + b;
std::cout << c << "\n";
```

}

Output-ello

why is output coming as ello, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

You do not add an integer and a string, you add an integer to a character pointer.

Adding 1 to a pointer lets it point to the next element, in your case the `'e'`.

Interpreting that new character pointer as a null-terminated string (which is what `std::cout` does when printing) gets you `"ello"`.

**Edit**: This looks like a classical case of using too much `auto`. In my opinion, when using `auto` the types should be absolutely obvious -- and initializing from a literal is often not (for everyone). Decorating it as `auto*` instead also can help the reader.